# How to set typescript type for key value in objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object of currency types with properties like this:

```
CurrencyType = {
  usd: {
    country: 'United States', 
    symbol: '$USD', 
    icon: <USD />
  }, 
  cad: {
    country: 'Canada', 
    symbol: '$CAD', 
    icon: <CAD />
  },
  etc...
}
```

How can I write the type so that it takes a dynamic value for the key of each object – `usd`, or `cad`

I am trying to find how I can set the typescript type for for this object above so that the object names are included.

Basically want something like this:

```
export interface CurrencyTypes {

   [currencyName: string]: {
      country: string;
      symbol: string;
      icon: React.ReactNode; 
   }
```

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking for.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior i've added more info if that helps, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for something like this where you iterate over the values of another type.

```js
type CountryCurrency = "usd" | "cad" | "aud";

export interface CurrencyTypes {
   [Currency in CountryCurrency]: {
      country: string;
      symbol: string;
      icon: React.ReactNode; 
   }
}
```

This will require that any object that implements the `CurrencyTypes` interface has all of the keys that are possible values of `CountryCurrency`

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for! 
It gives me an error though saying "A mapped type may not declare properties or methods."

Comment: do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @user3648969 I tried out the code above in my editor and it didn't give any errors. Did you add anything else that might be causing the error?